# Array in Excel Rank function

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the RANK function in Excel to give me the ranking of an entered number.  The number will be ranked between 11 and 55 ascending.  So if the user enters 11 in the cell, it should be ranked 1 and so on.  The problem is I can't get Excel to accept my array of numbers 11 through 55 to use in the rank formula.  How do I hard code the array values into the formula?  I have tried using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to get the array values in there.  I have tried setting up a named reference with all of the array values already set, and all sorts of other stuff.  Excel will only pull the first number from the array and fail on everything else.

```
=RANK(R4,ARRAY GOES HERE,1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put the numbers in a range and refer to that?

Comment: Is this "genuine" ranking? Is it possible, for example, that you only have 4 numbers to rank, which are as follows, 11, 11, 12 and 25. How would those be ranked in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
=INDEX(ROW($1:$44),MATCH(R4,ROW($11:$55),0))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

As @shrivallabha.redij stated the MATCH alone will work in this case:

```
=MATCH(R4,ROW($11:$55),0)
```

Comment: Wouldn't array entered `=MATCH(A2,ROW($A$11:$A$55),0)` part produce the same result?

Comment: @yes, I over thought it.

Comment: @Scott I think the formula should read =INDEX(ROW($1:$45),MATCH(R4,ROW($11:$55),0))

Answer (score 5):

At risk of being overly simplistic

```
=R4-10
```

Comment: Just had one of those, bang my head on the desk moments.  DUH!  It is like making 3 lefts to go right.

Comment: Don't say that - your answer I think was more in line with OP's intentions.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a solution. Here's non-CSE suggestion.

`=LOOKUP(A2,ROW($A$11:$A$55),ROW($A$1:$A$45))`